# Show that the familiar logistic map $x_{n+1} = sx_n(1 - x_n)$, can be recoded into the form $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + c$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, chaos-theory

What change of variables would trtansform the logistic equation into the Mandelbrot equation $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$?

Comment: AND: since we have different answers here, the next step is to check your answer!

Comment: Since the OP is still present on the site, they might wish to answer my comment on @distantTransformer's answer below.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
z= i \cdot s \cdot (x - 0.5),\quad c = 0.5 \cdot \sqrt{s}
$$

Comment: For the record, I do not understand this answer. If either the answerer or the author of the question could explain.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do the next trick:

$$z_n=f(x_n)$$

$$f(sx_n(1-x_n))=f(x_{n+1})=z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c = f(x_n)^2+c$$

So we want our transformation to fulfill:

$$f(sx_n-sx_n^2)-(f(x_n))^2= c$$

I guess you can check for $$f(x)=Ax+B$$, and then solve to find $A,B$.

$$A(sx-sx^2)+B-(A^2x^2+2ABx+B^2) = c$$
Because this should be valid for all $x$, we should have:
$$-As-A^2=0$$
$$-2BA+As=0$$
$$B-B^2=c$$
$A\neq 0$, thus: $A=-s$ and $B=s/2$, and we should also have $s/2-s^2/4=c$

Answer (score 2):

Using the change of variable $z_n=s\cdot(\frac12-x_n)$ yields $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$ with $c=\frac12s-\frac14s^2$.